# Override tableView.separatorStyle for a single cell or section

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I'm trying to set the `tableView.separatorStyle` to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` for a single section (or row, I suppose), but allow it to be set to the default for every other section.

As an example (of the *unintended* behavior):

[image: Row example]

While the rows at the bottom (and top) of the image should display the default gray line surrounding each section, for this particular section, even though I have set the `backgroundColor` of the cell to `[UIColor clearColor]`, I would also like to remove the separator from this particular section.

There don't seem to be any delegate/datasource methods that allow overriding this on a per-section basis. The documentation for the `separatorStyle` property mentions:

> UITableView uses this property to set the separator style on the cell returned from the delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:.

So it sounds like it's applied after I've built my cell, and the setter is only at the `UITableView` level, it is not visible at the `..Cell` level.

Comment: try like this. In tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath you can compare the section. if(indexPath.section==0){tableView.separatorStyle= UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;}else{//whatever you want}

Comment: If you want to use seperator for single section you can compare that section index with indexpath.section in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: @kalyanipuvvada Check your comments, you are adding same comment 3 times. Also post an answer not different comments.

Answer (score 2):

the `separatorStyle` property can't be used for a specific cell. It will be used for all the cells. If you want to add separators just for some cells, add a `UIView` inside the cell's vie that will act as a separator and set the `separatorStyle` to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`.

In `cellForRow..` you can check the cell that will be provided to the table view and decide if the separator should be visible or not.

Comment: Thanks - that was the solution I had seen elsewhere, but I was hoping for something a little more robust than having to draw the border manually. Fortunately I'm only targeting iOS 7 onward so I don't have to maintain multiple "schemes", but it would still be great to have a forwards-compatible solution.

Comment: @CraigOtis This will be forward and backward compatible since you are creating a view hierarchy that doesn't depend on any "special" iOS features. I used this approach in every project that I've done.

Comment: Right - but it *does* depend on the style of the operating system. If iOS 8 or iOS 9 removes the cell border entirely, or changes the width/color, I'll have to remember to maintain that change. I'm aiming for a solution that will leave as much of the style up to the OS.

Comment: Well even if you try to keep as much as possible of the iOS style you don't have the guarantee that the app will work/look the same in the next iOS version. These are just the risks of mobile app dev :)).

Answer (score 2):

Just set a custom separator inset of 1000 for cells that you don't want to have separators.